# plsql - call to procedure from another schema

Tags: security, plsql, schema, procedure

How I can execute procedure from another schema?
I try to put the schema before the proc name but it doesn't help.
maybe I need to grant or change the roles of the proc but I didnt know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't help"? Are you having an error? If so which one? If you know you have an issue about grants, have you tried some searching about that?

Answer (score 5):

The schema who owns the procedure you want to run has to grant the necessary privilege to you.

Thus:

```
SQL>  conn whoever/password
SQL>  grant execute on the_proc to your_user;
```

Now `your_user` can run it:

```
SQL>  conn your_user/password
SQL>  exec whoever.the_proc
```

Alternatively, a power use with GRANT ANY level privileges (or EXECUTE granted  WITH GRANT OPTION) can do the grants.

```
SQL>  grant execute on whoever.the_proc to your_user;
```